# How to send php array using json to jquery using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm building a calculator and getting the results by using ajax in jquery to send values to the php file and returning the results back to jquery.  I can get one result to return, but want to get two results that can be separated.  I tried doing this with [json from a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778593/ajax-post-success-data-can-you-separate-results), but can't get it to work. It appears that answer came from JQuery.  What am I leaving out?

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#loanamount").change(function() {
    var amount = $('#loanamount').val();
    var rate = $('#rate').val();
    var term = $('#term').val();
    $.post('superGlobalsGet.php', {amount: amount, rate: rate, term: term}, function(data) {
        $('#payment').html(data.payment); 
        $('#totalint').html(data.totalint);
    }, "json");
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['amount'], $_POST['rate'], $_POST['term'])) {
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $rate = $_POST['rate'];
        $term = $_POST['term'];
        $convertRate = $rate + 2;
        $newRate = $convertRate + 3;
        $convertTerm = $term + 4;
        $loanPay = $newRate + 5;
        $totInt = ($loanPay * $convertTerm) - $amount;

        echo json_encode(array("payment" => $loanPay, "totalint" => $totInt));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is there any errors in console? If no errors, add `console.log(data);` before `$('#payment').html(data.payment);` show result.

Comment: There are no results.  It seems to be a problem with jquery not finding the key for the array.

Comment: did you test the path of php file and checked if its linked with js or not?

Comment: There's no console errors in chrome.  The file name is correct.

Comment: You could try changing your $_POST to $_GET and then visit /superGlobalsGet.php?amount=1&rate=1&term=1 to make sure you are seeing the response you expect.  Also, in chrome in the debug panel you can view the request in the Network tab and see the response there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the content type before sending the response :

```
...
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("payment" => $loanPay, "totalint" => $totInt));
```

Comment: try console.log(data) to see what's happening